# Is there a better way to move between Django's views aside from pasting new url?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm learning to use Django to build my web application. I want to access another page through a link on the index page, but the browser keeps appending the file and app name to the request. 
How do I get the browser to switch through links without appending the directory name each time ?

I've tried using reg exp with the old url method but it doesn't seem to work

```
#   My project
#   urls.py     
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls')),


]
#  My app
#  urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('index/',include([
        path('', views.index,name="index"),
        path('theteam', views.theteam,name="theteam"),
        path('services',views.services,name="services"),
        path('quotes',views.quotes,name="quotes"),
        path('insurance',views.insurance,name="insurance"),
        path('contact',views.contact,name="contact"),
        path('thanks', views.thanks,name="thanks"),

        ])),


]

# Views
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index/index.html')

def theteam(request):
    return render(request, 'index/theteam.html')

def services(request):
    return render(request, 'index/services.html')

def quotes(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(request, '/thanks/')

    return render(request, 'index/quotes.html',  { 'form': form })

def insurance(request):
    return render(request, 'index/insurance.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'index/contact.html')

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, '/thanks.html')

#My Views HTML
 <div class="menu-bar ">
     <ul>
           <a href="{% url 'services' %}"> <li>Services</li></a>
           <a href="{% url 'theteam' %}"><li>The Team</li> </a>
           <a href="{% url 'quotes' %}"><li>Quotes</li> </a>
           <a href="{% url 'insurance' %}"> <li>Insurance</li></a>
           <a href="{% url 'contact' %}"><li>Contact Us</li></a>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

So far I've been able to visit each page by simply pasting "/index/template/" into the browser but I can't switch between using the links. MY expected result is to be able to switch between pages using the links.

Comment: Not sure why you are doing it that way. You should have the `index` path in the include statement in your main `urls.py` and you shouldn't have an include in the app's `urls.py`. See a Django tutorial for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

In your apps urls.py, add a line above urlpatterns that looks like:

```
app_name = your_app_name
```

Then, in your html file, change

```
{% url 'services' %}
```

to

```
{% url 'your_app_name:services' %}
```